# Jquery .val() method is not working when change text box ,

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been developing MVC3 application.this is my edit view, text box that i want to edit

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NoOfDays, new { @class="text_box_size",@size = "5" })
```

I use Jquery to change other text box according to value of above text box

```
$(function () {
            $("input#NoOfDays").change(function () {
                var value =$("#NoOfDays").val();

                validation();

            });
        });
```

after change text box value I call validation function that I have pre written.but its not working.Always return of the $("#NoOfDays").val(); function is old value.not new value.Please anyone can  help me

Comment: You're not doing anything with `value`. If `validation()` uses this, you need to pass it as an argument, e.g. `validation(value);`. Show us the definition of the function.

Comment: Works for me, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wep9m/). I also checked in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, since your question could use some work, but if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to update the value of some other textbox when the example you've shown changes. If that is correct, try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input#NoOfDays').on('blur', function (event) {
        var value = $(this).val();

        $('#id_of_other_textbox').val(value);

        // ... the rest of your code ...

    });
});
```

`on` requires jQuery 1.7 or better.

HTH.

**EDIT:** The primary difference between using `on` (and then specifying the event(s) to handle) and `click` is that `on` is a delegate that can be used to handle multiple events, whereas `click` (obviously) only listens for `onclick` events. It's also useful if you want to bind to dynamic events; bind to a static parent, and then filter down to a selector that will match the dynamic elements:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container-id').on('blur', 'input.dynamic-element-class', function (event) {

        // ... the rest of your code ...

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much.IT WORKED
Can you explain me what is the difference between .change() and        on('blur', function (event)

Thanks Once Again!

Comment: @user1662380 If this answered your question, please mark it as such. I'll update the answer to address your question, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Provide updated value as a parameter :

```
$(function () {
            $("input#NoOfDays").change(function () {
                var value =$("#NoOfDays").val();    
                validation(value);    
            });
        });
```

If you are facing problem in .change, you can also do like this :

```
$("input#NoOfDays").live('change keyup', function() {
    do your code here ...
});
```

Comment: but i try your first approach but its not working.I want to know Is there any problem with model data.Because this text box already have value that coming from model

Comment: Its ok.When debuging using developer tool i check the value that  return from $("#NoOfDays").val() method , but its same old value.not change.i

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onchange try using onBlur event.

Thanks

Kaushik